# how to create file using MIDlet

Tags: java, java-me

```
    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       FileConnection fconn = null;
    try {
        fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///D:/aaa.txt",Connector.READ_WRITE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(fconn.exists()){
        System.out.println("file is created");
    }
```

Comment: the above code is not creating a file.how to do that?

Comment: First line was outside of code block, improved indenting, added `java` tag so the syntax is colored appropriately

Comment: Do you intend to run the MIDlet on a Java ME capable device like an old mobile phone? This can be a very adventurous task to say the least. Not all Java ME capable devices support all functions of Java ME (JSR 75). If you intend to write an application for Android, this does not use Java ME.

Comment: thank you for your response.I solved the above problem.

Comment: could you please tell me how to use openOutputStream , openInputStream. while writing content of one directory to another. and how to list out all the files available in a directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience with Java ME is very limited because I haven't touched it for at least 10 years now so I can't, but would you mind posting how you solved the problem?